# How to filter distinct objects in a many-to-many relationship in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a page where I show all workout plans from each user. But I want to show only one entry per user, so then I can click and get all workouts plans of that user. So, instead of showing:

```
User 1 - Day 1
USer 1 - Day 2
User 2 - Day 1
USer 2 - Day 2
```

I want to show:

```
User 1
User 2
```

I was using the following view:

```
planos = Workout.objects.all()
```

But this would show everything, so I tried:

```
plan = Workout.objects.values('member').distinct()
```

But this returns `{'member': 1}` and `{'member': 2}`.

How can I access the name of the user?

```
class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    socio = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    

class Exercise(models.Model):
    exercise = models.CharField(max_length=166)
    series = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    reps = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    maquina = models.ForeignKey(Maquina)


class Workout(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Membro)
    day = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    exercises = models.ManyToManyField(Exercise)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You filter on the `Member` model:

```
Member.objects.filter(
    workout__isnull=False
).distinct()
```

This will make a LEFT OUTER JOIN on the `Workout` model, and thus retrieve `Member`s if (and only if) there is at least one related `Workout` object. The `.distinct()` will prevent that the same `Member` is returned multiple times.

We can also obtain the `User` models behind that member with:

```
User.objects.filter(
    member__workout__isnull=False
).distinct()
```

If you simply want to retrieve all members, you can work with `Member.objects.all()` and thus render these, and then ensure that one can click a link to get details for that `Member`.

Comment: Ok, this works to prevent an user to be returned multiple times. But if I want to still access the Workout id in the template with a loop? Could I loop with `member.workout.id`?

Comment: @JoãodeSousa: but the same user can have *multiple* workouts. `member.workout.id` thus makes not much sense, since it can contain an arbitrary number of workouts.

Comment: @JoãodeSousa: you can get all workout's with `member.workout_set.all` to access all the `workout`s of that `Member`.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't think of the correct thing. This works perfectly!